# Create bootstrap menu hamburger Icon displayed on medium devices (tablets) bot only in mobiles

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navigation menu with bootstrap.

I have a very similar menu with that [CodePen example.](http://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/bKFzD)

Is working the same like every normal nav bar

```css
.navbar, .navbar-inverse {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    min-height: 80px;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
    color: white;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 30px 25px 33px 25px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #444444;
    transition: 0.7s all linear;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--/ Bootstrap -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

but I want the hamburger icon displayed on medium devices Tablets as well as on mobiles.

Right now is only on mobiles.

Whats the best way to make it work?

Comment: Best way is to change the media query in CSS

Comment: it's easier in bootstrap 4, if you want to switch to that you can change the nav class like `navbar-toggleable-md`

Comment: @Brian just that? just changing class?

Comment: Have a look here: https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w/change-the-bootstrap-navbar-breakpoint

Comment: @Gerard thanks that very helpfull.. THat what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries and comments by [Gerard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3132019/gerard) using the media queries

> **Media queries**
>
> We use the following media queries in our Less files to
>   create the key breakpoints in our grid system.
>
> ```
> /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
> /* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */
>
> /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
> @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }
>
> /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
> @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }
>
> /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
> @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
> ```
>
> We occasionally expand on these media queries to include a max-width
>   to limit CSS to a narrower set of devices.
>
> ```
> @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }
> @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }
> @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }
> @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
> ```